# Implicit declaration of timersub() function in Linux - what must I define?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc

I am trying to compile timersub() function in linux but i always get:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:27:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘timersub’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  timersub(&now, &then, &diff);
  ^

/tmp/ccLzfLsl.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to `timersub'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

this is just a simple code of the function with all the library that i use..

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "openflow.h"
#include "cbench.h"
#include "fakeswitch.h"
#include <unistd.h>



int main()
{
    struct timeval now, then, diff;


    gettimeofday(&then,NULL);

    sleep(1);

    gettimeofday(&now, NULL);

    timersub(&now, &then, &diff);

return 0;


}
```

i am compiling it with:

gcc --std=c99 -Wall -DTRACE -o test test.c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/timersub). It's not in POSIX but in BSD function. So you need `_BSD_SOURCE`.

Define it at the top:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
```

or alternatively compile with:

```
gcc --std=c99 -Wall -DTRACE -D_BSD_SOURCE -o test test.c
```

Since Glibc 2.20, the macro `_BSD_SOURCE` has been deprecated and has been superseded by `_DEFAULT_SOURCE`. From [feature test macros](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html):

> _DEFAULT_SOURCE (since glibc 2.19)
>
> This macro can be defined to
>   ensure that the "default" definitions are provided even when the
>   defaults would otherwise be disabled, as happens when individual
>   macros are explicitly defined, or the compiler is invoked in one of
>   its "standard" modes (e.g., cc -std=c99).  Defining _DEFAULT_SOURCE
>   without defining other individual macros or invoking the compiler in
>   one of its "stan‐ dard" modes has no effect.
>
> The "default" definitions comprise those required by POSIX.1-2008 and
>   ISO C99, as well as various definitions originally derived from BSD
>   and System V.  On glibc 2.19 and earlier, these defaults were
>   approximately equivalent to explicitly defining the following:
>
> cc -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_SVID_SOURCE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809

But if you are using an older Gblic, you'd still need to use `_BSD_SOURCE`.

Comment: FYI My gcc compiler now (2016) says you should use _DEFAULT_SOURCE, not _BSD_SOURCE.

Comment: @moodboom Indeed. But `_BSD_SOURCE` might still be needed in older Glibc's. I have updated the answer to note the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Basically i just deleted #define _XOPEN_SOURCE and #define _POSIX_SOURCE and compiled it only with gcc -Wall -DTRACE and it worked